# The usage of "require" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

The verb "require" in this sentence from a [web page](https://www.amicalolafallslodge.com/ga-state-park/) strikes me as unusual.

> All cars **require** a $5 GA State Park Pass.

My understanding is that it is **the law/regulation** that requires a pass of cars. I thought the sentence should read:

> A $5 GA State Park Pass is required of all cars.

or

> All cars **need** a $5 GA State Park Pass.

While the meaning of the original sentence is crystal clear to me, I am wondering if its usage of **require** is a rare case or the author's peculiarity. **Require** appears to take on the meaning of "need" in that sentence. I have checked several dictionaries and can't find an example similar to that sentence. Although there is the definition of "*to demand as necessary or essential : have a compelling need for*" on M-W, it doesn't seem to fit in the context I am asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition of **require** from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/require) is

> to need something or make something necessary

... and in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/require) it is

> 1. Need for a particular purpose.

Those both fit the meaning in the sentence that you quoted, and in my opinion the Merriam-Webster definition "have a compelling need for" also works.

The Oxford dictionary provides an additional meaning- the one that you allude to in your question:

> 1.3 *with object and infinitive* (of someone in authority) instruct or expect (someone) to do something.

Note that in the main meaning, the object is the thing that is **needed**, whereas in the object+infinitive meaning, the object is the thing or person that **must** do something, as specified by the to-inifinitive.

Interestingly, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/require?src=search-dict-hed) does not refer to the object+infinitive meaning directly, but includes two recent examples that uses this form, in passive voice:

> The court is **required to** rule within 90 days... 
>   County commissioners, however, are not **required to** follow the staff's report...

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thank you. I guess this is where I was (or still is) stuck: Although some dictionary definitions do make sense in my quoted context, the example sentences under those sentences do not seem to be the same usage as my quoted sentence. For example in Cambridge Dictionary under the definition you cite: _If you require assistance with your bags, I’ll be glad to get someone to help you._ _This game requires total concentration._ Both these sentences can be explained by substituting **ask for** for **require**. _If you **ask for** assistance with your bags..._

Comment: The sentence at issue in my question, though, seems to be the opposite. Instead of **ask for**, _All cars are **asked for** a pass._ And this is the reason I am not so sure the sentence I ask about is one that fits those definitions.

Comment: @L.Moneta: I think that you are not interpreting the two examples correctly. You certainly **could** substitute **ask for** in the first sentence, but why would you? That is not what **require** means in any context, and in this context it definitely means **need**... "If you **need** assistance with your bags, I'll be glad to get someone to help you". And in the second sentence **asks for** doesn't work at all. Again, it means **needs**.

Answer (score 1):

Georgia law requires (makes compulsory) that cars have a state park pass; so cars in Georgia require (must have) such a pass to enter the park.  Many dictionaries give both meanings, so I'm not sure which ones you looked at, but I've a pretty good idea which ones you didn't look at ;)

Neither meaning is rare.

*You require food, clothing, and shelter for your continued existence.*

*The state requires you to pay taxes.* <sup>passive=></sup> *You are required by the state to pay taxes.*

*The state requires that you pay taxes.*

*It is required by the state that you pay taxes.*

Comment: "must have" is very helpful. +1 I did check several major dictionaries, but this is where I am still stuck: Although some dictionary definitions do make sense in my quoted context, the example sentences under those sentences do not seem to be the same usage as my quoted sentence. For example in Cambridge Dictionary: _If you require assistance with your bags, I’ll be glad to get someone to help you. This game requires total concentration._ Both these sentences can be explained by substituting **ask for** for **require**. _If you **ask for** assistance with your bags..._

Comment: The sentence at issue in my question, though, seems to be the opposite. Instead of ask for, _All cars are **asked** for a pass._ And this is the reason I am not so sure the sentence I ask about is one that fits those definitions.

Comment: The word **require** has both meanings: 1) to make something compulsory; to demand; to demand something of someone; and 2)  to need.   The entity from whom something is demanded *requires* it in sense #2, and the demanding entity *requires* it in sense #1. Since all drivers are asked to present their car's pass (the pass is demanded from them), all cars require a pass.